# probleme router with localstorage password

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i make a little application in vuejs i want stock a paswword in the localstorage but i have some problems with redirection and error (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded).
Do you have a soution for this ?

```
  if (!localStorage.passwordEm) {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log('foo');
    localStorage.passwordEm = 'init';
    next('login');
  } else if (localStorage.passwordEm !== 'super') {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log('bar');
    next('login');
  } else {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log('boz');
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You always redirect user here `next('login')` and call before each once and once again.

To solve that you need to rewrite your `beforeEach` logic:

```
  if (to.name === 'login') {
    next()
  } else if (!localStorage.passwordEm) {
  ...
```